# Integrating angular js on Yii Php without using node js and grunt

Tags: angularjs, yii

https://github.com/drumaddict/angular-yii --
This project contains node js etc..
I just wanna use Angulag js into YII..Please help me on this?
and where can i add js files?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS is a front-end framework that can communicate with different server side languages. Your back-end could be built with PHP or NodeJs or Ruby or whatever, it will most likely act as an API and just send raw of data as JSON format.

In the case of your example, NodeJs is used on development environment to manage within npm many useful packages such as grunt or gulp, tests ....

you may start by reading this good blog post :

[Your First AngularJS App Tutorial Part 2: Tools for Scaffolding, Building, and Testing](http://www.toptal.com/angular-js/your-first-angularjs-app-part-2-scaffolding-building-and-testing)